# Dynamic Programming: Tabulation of a Recursive Relation

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, dynamic-programming, coin-change

The following recursive relation solves a variation of the coin exchange problem. Count the number of ways in which we can sum to a required value, while keeping the number of summands even:

```
def count_even(coins, num_coins, req_sum, parity):
    if req_sum < 0:
        return 0
    if req_sum == 0 and not parity:
        return 1
    if req_sum == 0 and parity:
        return 0
    if num_coins == 0:
        return 0
    count_wout_high_coin = count_even(coins, num_coins - 1, req_sum, parity)
    count_with_high_coin = count_even(coins, num_coins, req_sum - coins[num_coins - 1], not parity)
    return count_wout_high_coin + count_with_high_coin
```

This code would yield the required solution if called with `parity = False`.

I am having issues implementing a tabulation technique to optimize this algorithm. On a first attempt I tried to follow the same pattern as for other DP problems, and took the parity as another parameter to the problem, so I coded this triple loop:

```
def count_even_tabulation(S, m, n):
    if m <= 0 or n < 0:
        return 0
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    table = [[[0 for x in range(m)] for x in range(n + 1)] for x in range(2)]
    for j in range(m):
        table[0][0][j] = 1
        table[1][0][j] = 0
    for p in range(2):
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
            for j in range(m):
                y = table[p][i][j - 1] if j >= 1 else 0
                x = table[1 - p][i - S[j]][j] if i - S[j] >= 0 else 0
                table[p][i][j] = x + y
    return table[0][n][m - 1]
```

However, this approach is not creating the right tables for parity equal to 0 and equal to 1:

```
[1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]

[0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0]
```

How can I adequately implement a tabulation approach for the given recursion relation?

Comment: Can you give some example calls with input parameters and output? I'm not sure I understand. What does "keeping the number of summands even" mean? Does it mean to have an even number of coins in any one `way` that's part of the solution?